# Transparency in component component overlay

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl

First and foremost if more information is required please just ask i'm willing to add more information. (Won't be able to answer earlier until tomorrow 09:00 GMT+1)

Working on an application in delphi with rounded comboboxes and rounded buttons (TCustomControls) 
The problems that arise are mainly problems with components that are in some way layered over each other
as can be seen in image one (below)

The background of the form still shines through around the corners while the components are drawn on top of each other.

For every custom control I am painting the component myself. But I can't seem to get a grasp on how to get this to work as it should.

I've tried the following

```
 - Params.exStyle := Params.exStyle + WS_EX_TRANSPARENT; 
 - ScanLine and set the pixels equal to the background (which doesn't work as one
   would suspect)
 - WSEraseBackground procedure empty
```

But nothing seems to fix my problem (WS_EX_TRANSPARENT did but when clicking on a component it seems to flip the Z-order)

I override the paint event and just draw rounded rectangles (shouldn't be a biggy imo)

[image: Current Issue]

[image: How I would like to see it work]

```
procedure TRoundedComboBox.Paint;
var
  Rect : TRect;

  procedure DrawFirst();
  begin
    {first}
    Canvas.Pen.Color := FColorArray[0];
    Canvas.Brush.Color := FColorArray[0];
    Canvas.RoundRect(0,
                     0,
                     width,
                     FDefaultComboBoxHeight,
                     20,
                     20);
  end;


  procedure DrawFirstInner();
  begin
    {first inner}
    Canvas.Pen.Color := FColorArray[1];
    Canvas.Brush.Color := FColorArray[1];
    Canvas.RoundRect(0,
                     1,
                     width,
                     FDefaultComboBoxHeight,
                     20,
                     20);
  end;


  procedure DrawSecondInner();
  begin
    {second inner}
    Canvas.Pen.Color := FColorArray[2];
    Canvas.Brush.Color := FColorArray[2] ;
    Canvas.RoundRect(0,
                     round(FDefaultComboBoxHeight /2),
                     width,
                     FDefaultComboBoxHeight,
                     20,
                     20);
  end;


  procedure DrawText();
  begin
    {Text}
    Canvas.Font := FFont;
    Canvas.Font.Color := FColorArray[3];
    Canvas.Brush.Style := bsClear;
    FTextRect := TRect.Create(4, 0, width -20, FDefaultComboBoxHeight);
    Canvas.TextRect(FTextRect,
                    12,
                    round(FTextRect.Height /2) - round(Canvas.TextExtent(FText).Height /2),
                    FText);
  end;


  procedure DrawTriangle();
  begin
    {Triangle}
    Canvas.MoveTo(FPoints[0].x, FPoints[0].y);
    Canvas.Pen.Color := FColorArray[4];
    Canvas.Brush.Color := FColorArray[4];
    Canvas.Polygon(FPoints);
  end;

begin
  //inherited;

  FListBox.Invalidate;
  FListBox.Visible := FEnabledBtnDown;

  if (FEnabledBtnDown) then
  begin
    FlistBOx.SetFocus;
  end;


  Height := IfThen (FEnabledBtnDown, FMaxmimumComboBoxHeight, FDefaultComboBoxHeight);

  DrawFirst;

  DrawFirstInner;

  DrawSecondInner;

  DrawTriangle;

  DrawText;
end;
```

Comment: Please include the code you're using to do the painting.

Comment: I would simply [`SetWindowRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145102(v=vs.85).aspx) to a round rectangle region for such controls.

Comment: @TLama whats the impact on Setting the WindowRgn (I've seen it in an example) but what if I draw (for example) 100 comboboxes this way. Does it take relative lots of resources??

Comment: @KenWhite I've added the code of the paint procedure

Comment: The calls to `Invalidate`, `Visible`, `SetFocus` and `Height := ` don't really belong inside the Paint Event. That is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @Blaatz0r, hard to say. At least it would consume 100 of regions owned by the system. Another downside is that the edges of a round rectangle region are not smooth (but your drawing is not antialiased as well).

Comment: @SebastianZ your right but for the example it wouldn't have any negative impact in on the situation as explained. e.g. the invalidate is on another component same as the visible and setfocus. the height is indeed on the 'Self' so that might retrigger another invalidate. But I understand your response.

Comment: @TLama for now it is not antialiased but if this works I want to port the code to GDI+ and use antialiasing.

Answer (score 1):

You could derive from TCustomTransparentControl (unit Controls.pas). If that is not an option, take a look at how TCustomTransparentControl works.

Comment: Seems plausible I've tried to derive from TCustomTransparentControl before. But the same happened with the Z order as stated before. I'll have a look in how the control works perhaps I can figure out some more information